Issues Importing Excel Data with BelongsTo Relationship in Filament
I am trying to import data from an Excel file into my laravel Filament (V3) application , but I'm having trouble with importing relationships. Specifically, I have a Stock model that has a belongsTo relationship with a Supplier model. During the import, I want to set the supplier_id based on the supplier's name provided in the Excel file.
Here is the code for my StockImporter class:
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Imports;

use App\Models\Stock;
use App\Models\Supplier;
use Filament\Actions\Imports\ImportColumn;
use Filament\Actions\Imports\Importer;
use Filament\Actions\Imports\Models\Import;

class StockImporter extends Importer
{
    protected static ?string $model = Stock::class;

    public static function getColumns(): array
    {
        return [
            ImportColumn::make('name')
                ->requiredMapping()
                ->rules(['required', 'max:255']),
            ImportColumn::make('description'),
            ImportColumn::make('quantity')
                ->requiredMapping()
                ->numeric()
                ->rules(['required', 'integer']),
            ImportColumn::make('minimum_quantity')
                ->requiredMapping()
                ->numeric()
                ->rules(['required', 'integer']),
            ImportColumn::make('supplier_id')
                ->relationship(resolveUsing: function (string $state): ?Supplier {
                    $supplier = Supplier::query()
                        ->where('name', $state)
                        ->first();

                    return $supplier ? $supplier->id : null;
                }),
            ImportColumn::make('order_id')
                ->rules(['max:255']),
            ImportColumn::make('supplier_order_id')
                ->rules(['max:255']),
            ImportColumn::make('purchase_price')
                ->numeric()
                ->rules(['integer']),
            ImportColumn::make('sale_price')
                ->numeric()
                ->rules(['integer']),
        ];
    }

    public function resolveRecord(): ?Stock
    {
        // return Stock::firstOrNew([
        //     // Update existing records, matching them by `$this->data['column_name']`
        //     'email' => $this->data['email'],
        // ]);

        return new Stock();
    }

    public static function getCompletedNotificationBody(Import $import): string
    {
        $body = 'Your stock import has completed and ' . number_format($import->successful_rows) . ' ' . str('row')->plural($import->successful_rows) . ' imported.';

        if ($failedRowsCount = $import->getFailedRowsCount()) {
            $body .= ' ' . number_format($failedRowsCount) . ' ' . str('row')->plural($failedRowsCount) . ' failed to import.';
        }

        return $body;
    }
}

quick summary:

I am using Filament for handling the import.
The Stock model has a belongsTo relationship with the Supplier model.
I want to import the supplier_id based on the supplier's name provided in the Excel file.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
UPDATE:
I've changed the ImportColumn for supplier to:
 ImportColumn::make('supplier_id')
            ->label('Supplier Name')
            ->relationship(
                resolveUsing: function (string $state): ?int {
                    $supplier = Supplier::query()
                        ->where('name', $state)
                        ->first();
                    return $supplier?->id;
                }
            ),

This prevents the "running FAIL" from my queue:work process. When I get that error I now run a php artisan migrate fresh to be able to test it again.
However this code return null. Both on supplier name and ID.
